# How trigger counter cache after destroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel, counter-cache

I have to destroy a big list of data, and update my counter cache, but when I user destroy_all counter cache is called at every delete. Is there any way to update my counter only after the destroy_all?

I already tried ActiveModel Callbacks, but they are the same as destroy_all, called one time for each record.

```rb
  belongs_to :research, counter_cache: :total_participants
```

```rb
  ResearchParticipant.from_research(@research_id).destroy_all
```

Comment: `destroy_all` invokes all callbacks (including updating counter cache columns), `delete_all` does not trigger any callback, you have to update the value of the counter cache column manually at the end though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`delete_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-delete_all) which doesn't instantiate objects. Meaning callbacks aren't called. Then reset the cache with [`reset_counters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_counters).

```
ResearchParticipant.from_research(@research_id).delete_all
Research.reset_counters(@research_id, :research_participants)
# assuming Research has_many :research_participants, counter_cache: :total_participants
```

If you depend on callbacks that must be triggered this might not be an option.